# custom views & perspectives in Pimcore 4 to use user roles for custom reports visibility

Tags: pimcore

We are trying to share custom reports in Pimcore 4 with several users grouped by roles. Whereas the visibility of documents, assets & objects can be administered in the configuration this seems not possible for custom reports.

Is there a workaround in Pimcore 4 to hide custom reports between roles of business users by combining custom views & different perspectives per user role? In detail, can we create custom views in Pimcore showing only subsets of our marketing reports and bind that view via perspective to a user role?

Answer (score 0):

right now this is not implemented in Pimcore yet. 
But you can create a issue at Pimcore to discuss that with the core team.

Cheers...

Christian